# MapThread conflicting with DynamicModule

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, programming, user-interface

*Cross-posted: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1625808*

**Answer posted on [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1625808?p_p_auth=IUxNI68R)**

I'm creating an interactive UI which allows the user to import data from a spreadsheet, perform calculation and plot the results. The issue I'm having is with `MapThread`, which is evaluated at the same time as the `DynamicModule`, giving an error message that dimensions of objects are incompatible. I noticed that outputs of dynamically displayed objects such as buttons in this case are retained in the memory and used as initial values every time `DynamicModule` is re-evaluated (specifying initial values didn't help), and because dimensions of these objects are different at the point of `DynamicModule` re-evaluation further output of `ListPlot` is suppressed before any action is taken. I'm struggling to get around this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
DynamicModule[{userSystemWindow = {}},
 Dynamic @ Column[{
    Row[(*Load Data Button*)
     {Button[
       "Load Geometry",
       userSystemWindow = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"];
       importedData = 
        If[ToString[userSystemWindow] != "$Canceled", 
         Flatten[Import[userSystemWindow, "XLSX"], 1] // Rest, {}],
        Method -> "Queued"] }],
    Spacer[1], Style[
     Dynamic@Grid[{(*Calculate Button*)
        {Button[
          "Calculate", 
          calculatedList1 = Table[1, {N[Length[importedData] - 1]}];

      For[l = 2, l <= Length[importedData], l++, 
       calculatedList1[[l - 1]] = 
        Sqrt[(importedData[[l, 1]] - 
             importedData[[l - 1, 1]])^2 + (importedData[[l, 2]] -
              importedData[[l - 1, 2]])^2]]; 
      PrependTo[calculatedList1, 0];
      calculatedList2 = Table[1, Length[importedData]];

      For[t = 2; calculatedList2[[1]] = 170, 
       t <= Length[importedData], t++, 
       calculatedList2[[t]] = 

        10 + (calculatedList2[[t - 1]] - 10)*
          Exp[-N[Pi]*0.345*5*calculatedList1[[t]]/(10*2000)]],
      Method -> "Queued", ImageSize -> {75, 27}, 
      ContentPadding -> True, 

      Enabled -> (If[
         ToString[userSystemWindow] === "$Canceled" \[Or] 
          ToString[userSystemWindow] === "{}", False, True])], 
     (*Clear Results Button*)
     Button[
      "Clear Plot", calculatedList2 = {0}]}}]],
Spacer[1],
Dynamic@Grid[{
   {"Temperature Units", 
    PopupMenu[Dynamic[temperatureUnits], {
      celsius -> "C",
      fahrenheit -> "F"}]}}], 
Spacer[1],
(*Graph Plot*) 
ListPlot[
 If[Dimensions[importedData[[All, 1]]] === 
   Dimensions[calculatedList2], temperatureUnits, {}],
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Distance [m]",
    Switch[temperatureUnits, 
    celsius, "Temperature [C]",
     fahrenheit, "Temperature [F]"]},
  ImageSize -> 500, Joined -> True]
}, Alignment -> Left],
 Initialization :> (
   celsius = 
    MapThread[List, {importedData[[All, 1]], calculatedList2}];
   fahrenheit = 
    MapThread[
     List, {importedData[[All, 1]], 
      QuantityMagnitude@
       UnitConvert[QuantityArray[calculatedList2, "DegreesCelsius"], 
        "DegreesFahrenheit"]}];
   ), 
 SynchronousInitialization -> False
 ]
```

**Edit:**

This a description of what the UI should calculate.

At first the UI should display:

- 3 buttons: "Load Data", "Calculate Data" and "Clear Plot" (the last 2
  should initially be disabled);
- popup menu which is linked to the graph allowing the user to change
  the temperature unit of plotted data;
- graph which initially should be blank just showing frames and labels

Button "Load Data" upon mouse-click should open system dialog window, allowing the user to select the excel file with data which upon file selection are imported in the form `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}`. In case the user clicks on button "Load Data" but decides to cancel the selection and close the system dialog window the button “Calculate” should remain disabled with a graph being blank.

Button “Calculate” should become enable as soon as data is imported, which upon  mouse-click should solve couple of equations using imported data and inputs from `InputField`’s (removed from the code posted here) returning result of final equation in the form `{z1, z2, …}`.

When the data is ready to be plotted  `ListPlot` should automatically plot data in the form `{{x1, z1}, {x2, z2}, …}` with temperature unit `DegreesCelsius`. This is why I need to use `MapTherad` to combine the first column from imported data with the calculated data set of `z`’s. Then every time the user decides to change the input data or import new data and press the button “Calculate” `ListPlot` should update accordingly and plot new set of data by adding the new curve to the old one i.e. {list1, list2, ….} where each list corresponds to mouse-click, so the user can compare different results.

Button “Clear Plot”  is there to bring the plot to the blank state. I hope all that makes sense.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90716/discussion-on-question-by-kamila-mapthread-conflicting-with-dynamicmodule).

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you have to be a bit careful when mixing synchronous and asynchronous dynamics in one application. Synchronous dynamics will interrupt asynchronous ones, resulting in behavior that's difficult to anticipate. Here's an idiom I frequently use for initializing `DynamicModule`s that need a non-trivial amount of time to get themselves ready:

```
DynamicModule[{
  initQ = False
 },
 Dynamic[
  If[TrueQ[initQ],
   Dynamic[content],
   ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Necklace"]
   ],
  TrackedSymbols :> {initQ}
  ],
 SynchronousInitialization -> False,
 Initialization :> (
   initQ = False;
   Pause[6]; (* any pre-computation that takes significant time goes here *)
   initQ = True
  )
]
```

In this case, `Dynamic[content]` is the thing you actually want to show, but it will only appear after the initialisation has finished.

Answer (score 4):

Updating answer (meaning replacing it completely).

Right now your `Initialization` depends on values that aren't set until the body executes, but the body doesn't execute until after the initialization, and the initialization only executes once. So you need to have those set *a priori*. Putting this in up front, along with setting `importedData` lets it start up without a bunch of errors.

```
calculatedList2 = Table[1, Length[importedData]];
```

Then you can call your `DynamicModule[ ]`.

Comment: MikeY your suggestion unfortunately doesn't work, I'm still getting an error message such as:  MapThread: Incompatible dimensions of objects at positions {2, 1} and {2, 2} of MapThread[List,{{},{0}}]; dimensions are 0 and 1. The problem is that `MapThread` evaluates as soon as `DynamicModule` is displayed, using last output of dynamic objects as initial values.  Another problem is that `MapThread` evaluates only once and it doesn't update when the data is imported and button "Calculate" is clicked, at which point output of the button should be plotted.

Comment: I tried to use `Dynamic` with it but `ListPlot` doesn't accepts `Dynamic` inside. Maybe there is other way to combine 2 lists without using `MapThread` that wouldn't result in such error?

Comment: Yeah, did a little more digging...not working. It looks like the fundamental problem is your `Initialization` depends on `calculatedList2`, but the Initialization is guaranteed to get computed before the body, and you first compute `calculatedList2` *in* the body.

Comment: Anything you use in the Initialization gets called exactly once, and needs to be set in advance.

Comment: Errors start popping up after importing data and using button "Calculate" :(

Comment: Think you need to start with a clean sheet on your question. Describe what you want the UI to calculate. We can probably help you from there.